# np.where not returning any index on list of strings

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use np.where to access the index number of a string in a list of strings. This is for the setup of an automated simulation to keep track of the current and completed scenarios. I was unable to get a similar version of the following script to produce correct results. An empty array is returned when I expect index 1 to be returned.

```
 import numpy as np

 scenariolist=['scenario.npz', 'scenario1.npz', 'scenario2.npz']
 currscenario='scenario1.npz'

 print(np.where(scenariolist==currscenario))
```

Returns:

```
 (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Convert your list and string to numpy arrays?

Comment: Aha, it worked! I figured it was something simple :)

Comment: `where` only returns indices if there are `True` elements in the test.  If nothing matches the '==' test, the where list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, converting both arguments for `np.where()` to numpy arrays as follows, will give the expected result:

```
scenariolist=np.array(['scenario.npz', 'scenario1.npz', 'scenario2.npz'])
currscenario=np.array(['scenario1.npz'])

print(np.where(scenariolist==currscenario)) #(array([1]),)
```

Although, it can be done without using numpy arrays but the `index()` method for python lists:

```
scenariolist.index(currscenario) # 1
```

But if the value is not in the list, its necessary to handle `ValueError` exception.

```
try:
    scenariolist.index(currscenario) # 1 
except ValueError:
    print('currscenario is not in the list')
```